# If $f(c_i)=g(c_i)$ for $i=0,1,...,n$, prove that $f(x)=g(x)$ in $F[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Here is a problem I'm trying to solve:

> Let $F$ be a field. Let $f(x),g(x)\in F[x]$ have degree $\leq n$ and let each $c_i$ be a distinct element of $F$. If $f(c_i)=g(c_i)$ for $i=0,1,...,n$, prove that $f(x)=g(x)$ in $F[x]$.

My first thought was to use the Factor Theorem and show that $(x-c_i)\mid f(x)-g(x)$, for each $c_i$. This means that $f(x)-g(x)= k\prod_{i=0}^{n} (x-c_i)$, where $k$ is a constant in $F$. However I can't see how to move on from here to get $f(x)-g(x)=0_F$.

Any hints as to how I should proceed will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Let $h=f-g$. Then $h$ has degree at most $n$ and $n+1$ zeros.

Comment: Oh of course... and thus $h$ must be the zero polynomial. Thanks!